# 24v Emergency Stop Input

Tags: embedded, opto-isolator, mbed

What's a good way to read a 24v emergency stop signal with an mbed?

The 24v signal is connected to an E-stop contactor which disconnects power to a motor when the 24v is interrupted (i.e. when e-stop button is pressed).

I need a good way to read when the 24v signal is interrupted with an mbed. 
Would an opto-coupler be a good way to isolate the signal and lower the voltage to a value which the mbed could tolerate.

Comment: I think you would want to rectify it to DC filter it a little bit, then feed it to an opto. Otherwise it will pulse on and off at 2x line frequency. I don't know what an mbed is, though. If it has smarts, you could feed the pulsing signal directly to the mbed, and the mbed could somehow figure out when the pulsing stops that power has been interrupted.

Comment: add an extra contact ot the E-stop and wire that to your mbed, don't mess with safety equipment.

Comment: @mkeith: It's more likely to be 24 V DC as used in industrial control systems.

Comment: Oh. OK. So no filtering needed. Maybe the OP can clarify just for the sake of being certain that it is 24VDC.

Comment: @mkeith, yes it is 24v as used in industry.

Comment: @Jasen, if I wire an extra contact, how should I lower the voltage to a level which the mbed can accept?

Comment: Well, I fully believe Transistor that 24VDC is standard in industrial controls. But you have not exactly clarified anything by saying that it is "24v as used in industry." Because 24VAC is also widely used as a low voltage control signal for relays. Maybe not in industrial controls, but in other places.

Comment: @M-R you could connect it to the mbeds vcc instead of 24V

Comment: @Jasen, could you provide a diagram, to illustrate your point? Thanks

Comment: vcc --- switch ---{mbed gpio}---[10k]--- ground

Comment: @Jasen, thanks. How should I lower the voltage to ~3.3v before the mbed gpio? You previously suggested using the mbed's vcc, but wouldn't that just disconnect its power when the e-stop is engaged?

Comment: take the power from the mbed to an unused contact on the emergency stop switch, add one if there is not a spare - those switches are usually modular.

Comment: @Jasen, Ohhhh, so effectively you would have two channels; 1 for the motor relay, and one for the mbed?

Comment: @Jasen That's likely not an option, if the MCU device is some 3rd party device. There may also be more than one emergency stop, and there's no guarantee they are multi-pole or free. And nobody will want to install wires all over, on a present application. If there is just one stop and it is designed & delivered by the same person providing the MCU solution, then yeah that would be a great solution. Doesn't sound likely though.

Comment: many industrial controls are modular and additional contacts can easily be added.

Answer (score 1):

Here is kind of a sketch to get you on the right track. The ESTOP_SW controls the coils for both the detect relay and the machine contactor. So when the contactor is energized, the detect relay is energized and ESTOP_DETECT will be low.

When someone pushes the ESTOP_SW and opens the circuit, then the contactor and relay will be de-energized, the machine will be stopped, and ESTOP_DETECT will be high.

R1 is on the MBED. The MBED may have outputs that can be configured to have pullups (you may not need to modify the MBED). If so, use one of those, and configure it so the pullup is enabled.

NOTE: if there is a possibility of property damage or personal injury, please hire a professional engineer with liability insurance to review your installation. This is just a sketch to give you a rough idea. Lots of things could go wrong, and I have no idea what your installation is like.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fidL6i.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This is completely overkill for the average 24V vehicle application and also dangerous. You can connect the MCU to the 24V emergency stop signal without galvanic insulation. A voltage divider, some diodes for protection and a series resistor like the one in the picture will work just fine. A relay on the other hand, introduces a notable hazard, since they will eventually break. You'd need to use safety relays with supervision, which is what's used to activate the stop from electronics.

Comment: Why do you think it is a vehicle application? No answer has been accepted. So you should maybe write your own answer.

Comment: I mentioned vehicle applications because that's likely the worst case, with surges etc.

Comment: I posted an answer. The key here is that regular relays and optocouplers is a big no-no on a safety function. When they break they may do so in a dangerous state (bureaucrats call this parameter "MTTF(d)", mean time to dangerous failure, and a plain relay will have a horrible MTTF(d)). Unlike plain passives and diodes which will in worst case just fry and leave the circuit dead in a safe state - which is preferable to a MCU making the wrong decisions.

Comment: @Lundin, we don't even know if it is a safety function. The OP wants to detect when E-stop is active. I put a disclaimer in my answer because there may be many potential hazards. Most of the circuitry in my schematic is just meant to represent existing circuitry. Only the detect relay is what I am adding.

Comment: One is not allowed to use the term "emergency stop" if it is not a safety function. Anyway, it is a fact that relays (and optocouplers) eventually break and the design must take this in account.

Comment: We don't know what the OP is doing with the information. The relay may break, but the only consequence would be that the Mbed (whatever it is) would then have an incorrect idea of the state of estop. That could be critical and tragic or it could be a minor inconvenience. We don't know.

Answer (score 0):

For the average industrial/automotive 24V application, you can solve this with passives and some diodes. Using relays or optocouplers is not recommended, since they will eventually break, possibly in a dangerous state. Passives/diodes are much more reliable, and if they break, they shouldn't leave the circuit in a dangerous state.

As an industry de facto standard rule, all relays interacting with an emergency stop has to be supervised 2 pole safety relays with mechanical latching. But that's not at all necessary here since you don't want to control the stop, but just passively read the stop state.

Design a voltage divider (R1, R2) from the 24V. If you know you have a good 24V, then design for 24V, otherwise go with 30-32V (automotive applications). Divide this down to your MCU voltage level. This voltage divider should also act as a current limiter so pick high resistance values.

Then use fast signal diodes to protect the input from bad voltages: one of them to ground, the other to your MCU voltage minus diode forward voltage. You can get this voltage through a zener diode, here assuming MCU voltage = 3.3V and diode forward voltage roughly 7V.

If you are feeling a bit paranoid, you can add an extra current-limiting resistor towards the MCU pin and a TVS diode (33V 1500W for automotive/industrial grade) on the input.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJFkFF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For a safety-critical stop supervision, you might want to consider "redundancy" - that is, having two identical circuits doing the same thing, arranged so that they must come to the same conclusion.

Comment: This circuit has a potential problem if there is ever a case when U1 is not powered, but Emgy 24V is present. In that case U1 may try to power up from current flowing through R1 and Roptional. The OP does not seem to be an advanced designer, so you may want to mention that in your answer, or even add isolation circuitry powered from U1's VDD.

Comment: @mkeith Indeed. Ideally the power would be taken from an external 24V supply and not from the emergency stop. Because the emergency stop will get its power from that same supply too.